# How can we use on_update CASCADE in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

**Scenario:** We have a table of members in our schema which has foreign key references to multiple tables on a certain attribute in member table: member_id (which is explicitly generated during member creation which is unique for every member). 
Example: 
Member table

```
id member_id first_name last_name
-- --------- ---------- -------
12 xyzqfad   Test       Member
```

Transactions table

```
txn_id txn_value member_id
------ --------- --------------
425    500       xyzqfad
```

**Requirement:** When we are deleting the member we want to modify the member_id some other value

Final state:
Member table

```
id  member_id   first_name  last_name
--  ---------   ----------  ------
12  MASKED12    ******      ******
```

Transactions table

```
txn_id txn_value member_id
------ --------- ---------
425    500       MASKED12
```

**Problem:** We are unable to modify the member_id due to the presence of foreign key references on member_id in other tables.

Answer (score 1):

Django allows you to set the [`on_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) attribute on the related field so that you can specify what you want to happen when the related object is deleted.

> When an object referenced by a `ForeignKey` is deleted, Django will emulate the behavior of the SQL constraint specified by the `on_delete` argument.

Based on what you've said, you want to use the `SET()` functionality which calls a function in order to set a value upon deletion of the related object.

Example taken from Django docs;

> Set the `ForeignKey` to the value passed to `SET()`, or if a callable is passed in, the result of calling it. In most cases, passing a callable will be necessary to avoid executing queries at the time your `models.py` is imported:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models

def get_sentinel_user():
    return get_user_model().objects.get_or_create(username='deleted')[0]

class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.SET(get_sentinel_user),
    )
```

In this example, there would be a generic "deleted user" which would be the link to all objects where their user is deleted.

Because it's an FK that you're working with, you need to set the value to an object of that related table to fulfil the database constraint, but I'm sure you could do something similar to this to achieve what you want.